# Trying to extend the typing indicator for discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

As far as I know the new discord.js update merged `typingStart` and `typingStop` into one, and set the time limit of `sendTyping()` to only 10 seconds. The thing I'm trying to get working is to allow the typing indicator of the bot to go beyond the 10 seconds limit, as the retrieval of the API request can, and usually goes beyond 10 to 20 seconds.

I have tried to set an interval where the function would repeat after 5 seconds but it would still end after the first iteration.

```
const awaitTypingState = await message.channel.sendTyping();
const typingInterval = setInterval(function() { awaitTypingState; }, 5000);
```

I also set a clear interval in the event that the API has responded to the request

```
if (response) { setTimeout(function() { clearInterval(typingInterval); }, 50000); }
```

Could be my lack of understanding with the module, but I just find it weird that `setInterval` does not repeat the typing indicator and instead just ends.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you are only calling the function once, on first line, inside the setInterval callback you are just referencing the value returned by the sendTyping function.

You should instead put the sendTyping into the setInterval function like this:

```js
const typingInterval = setInterval(function() { message.channel.sendTyping(); }, 5000);
```

By the way, the 10s is what discord applies on their end (https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#trigger-typing-indicator) I'd assume that is to stop broken bots and glitched clients from not sending the stopTyping command.

Comment: With this approach the indicator only shows up after the API response has been made, and the main issue still persists, where it ends after the 10 second period.